# State Management through Sql Server 2005

Tags: asp.net, session-state

How we have to store session state in database???
Is there any configuration to store the Session & Application variables in SQL Server 2005 database.

Comment: I don't know if it's an option in your case, but you should seriously consider not using session state at all.  In practice, it is a very brittle solution, since you can't always count on the survival of a session cookie.  Use post data (view state) to carry information across pages in multi-page forms, and place anything that needs to be persistent into a database, keyed on something more permanent than a session ID.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean in asp.net (if you don't remove the tag I just added) then follow [these instructions](http://idunno.org/articles/277.aspx)

Comment: I run this command on command promt 
OSQL -S SQLEXPRESS -E <InstallSqlState.sql
Getting error 
[SQL Native Client]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL
Server [53].
[SQL Native Client]Login timeout expired
[SQL Native Client]An error has occurred while establishing a connection to
the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by
the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote
connections.

How i run that script???? I have not query analyzer.

Comment: Then install Management studio express from http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en

But you do NOT want to do this with SQL Express, that's kind of pointless. SQL session state is there to share state between multiple web servers. If you're using SQL Express that indicates you're using a single machine, so why bother with SQL session state.

Comment: I download & install SQLServer2005_SSMSEE.msi it successfully installed. then i run the Management studio express it shows unhandled exception. when i continue this i m able to connect the SQL express. then what i do?? because when i click on open exception occur & studio close automatically. How i run that script..

Comment: Can u suggest me how can i do the same through oracle.

Comment: Then it sounds like you've bodged up the install somewhere. If you're determined to waste time storing state in SQL Express on a single server then I suggest you uninstall MSE and SQL Express 2005 then start again using the SQL Express with Advanced Services which includes MSE - http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/express-down.aspx

Comment: I am using SQL Server Express for experimental purpose only.
I want to use Oracle database for state management. Can you suggest some good tutorial for using oracle database for state management?

Comment: I don't know if Oracle even provide a state provider.

Answer (score 1):

> By default, session state values and
>   information are stored in memory
>   within the ASP.NET process.
>   Alternatively, you can store session
>   data in a SQL Server database, where
>   it can be shared by multiple Web
>   servers. For more information about
>   session state, see Implementing a
>   Session-State Store Provider and
>   Session-State Modes.
>
> If the database that you specify for
>   session state with Aspnet_regsql.exe
>   does not already exist, then the
>   current user must have rights to
>   create databases in SQL Server as well
>   as to create schema elements within a
>   database. If the database does exist,
>   then the current user must have rights
>   to create schema elements in the
>   existing database.
>
> To install the session state database
>   on SQL Server, run Aspnet_regsql.exe
>   tool supply the following information
>   with the command:
>
> - The name of the SQL Server instance, using the **-S** option.
> - The logon credentials for an account that has permission to create
>     a database on a computer running SQL
>     Server. Use the **-E** option to use
>     the currently logged-on user, or use
>     the -U option to specify a user ID
>     along with the -P option to specify a
>     password.
> - The **-ssadd** command-line option to add the session state database.
>
> By default, you cannot use
>   Aspnet_regsql.exe to install the
>   session state database on a computer
>   running SQL Server 2005 Express
>   Edition. For more information about
>   using SQL Server 2005 Express Edition
>   to store session state, see
>   Session-State Modes.

From here: [ASP.NET SQL Server Registration Tool (Aspnet_regsql.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: I run this command at VS command promt aspnet_regsql.exe -S localhost -E -ssadd it gives error THe argument -ssadd is invalid.
what i do??

Comment: Try typing in the command instead of copy/pasting it. Worked for me.